# How to start the "while" loop again after it returning False?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

So, I just finished learning the basics of Python and wanted to make a small Rock, Paper, Scissors game to practice my knowledge.

Right now, this is my code so far;

```
from random import randint


pipisuyu = 1
while pipisuyu == 1:

    secim = input("Taas kagit....")
    AI = randint(0, 2)
    if secim == "Tas" and AI == 0:
        print ("Rakibiniz de Tas secti, berabere!")


    elif secim == "Tas" and AI == 1:
        print ("Rakibiniz kagit secmisti. Kaybettin!")
        pipisuyu -= 1
    elif secim == "Tas" and AI == 2:
        print ("Rakibiniz makas secmisti. Kazandiniz!")   
        pipisuyu -= 1
    elif secim == "Kagit" and AI == 0:  
        print ("Rakibiniz tas secmisti. Kazandiniz!")
        pipisuyu -= 1
    elif secim == "Kagit" and AI == 1: 
        print ("Rakibiniz de kagit secmisti. Berabere!")
    elif secim == "Kagit" and AI == 2:  
        print ("Rakibiniz makas secmisti. Kaybettiniz!")
        pipisuyu -= 1
    elif secim == "Makas" and AI == 0:
        print ("Rakibiniz tas secmisti. Kaybettiniz!")  
        pipisuyu -= 1
    elif secim == "Makas" and AI == 1:
        print ("Rakibiniz kagit secmisti. Kazandiniz!")  
        pipisuyu -= 1
    elif secim == "Makas" and AI == 2:
        print ("Rakibiniz de makas secmisti. Berabere!")
```

So, I want to make an option for this game in order to play again, which will bring me back to the while loop. At first I tried this;

```
if pipisuyu == 0:
    anan = input("Tekrar oynamak isterseniz ""tekrar"" yaziniz.")
    if anan == "tekrar":
        pipisuyu += 1
```

But it doesn't work, which I believe even though now pipisuyu equals 1, while loop is already done with it and doesn't work again.(?)

So, I would appreciate if someone can tell me, how can I get back to the while loop again, after losing or winning the game.

Comment: Another while loop!

Comment: You cannot move back to some instruction before. What you *can* do is repeat something. How do you repeat something? Using a loop. So use a loop to repeat the game until nobody wants to play again.

Comment: Put it in a function? what language is this? "pipisuyu "?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for everybodies' responses. And Samer Tufail, it is Turkish but just a silly slang word, please don't mind it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the game in a function and when pipisuyu is 0, call the run function again. Each time run is called pipisuyu will be reinitialized to 1. Be careful though, the only way to exit this game would be to force close your terminal.

```
from random import randint

def run():
    pipisuyu = 1
    while pipisuyu == 1:

        secim = input("Taas kagit....")
        AI = randint(0, 2)
        if secim == "Tas" and AI == 0:
            print ("Rakibiniz de Tas secti, berabere!")


        elif secim == "Tas" and AI == 1:
            print ("Rakibiniz kagit secmisti. Kaybettin!")
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Tas" and AI == 2:
            print ("Rakibiniz makas secmisti. Kazandiniz!")   
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Kagit" and AI == 0:  
            print ("Rakibiniz tas secmisti. Kazandiniz!")
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Kagit" and AI == 1: 
            print ("Rakibiniz de kagit secmisti. Berabere!")
        elif secim == "Kagit" and AI == 2:  
            print ("Rakibiniz makas secmisti. Kaybettiniz!")
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Makas" and AI == 0:
            print ("Rakibiniz tas secmisti. Kaybettiniz!")  
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Makas" and AI == 1:
            print ("Rakibiniz kagit secmisti. Kazandiniz!")  
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Makas" and AI == 2:
            print ("Rakibiniz de makas secmisti. Berabere!")

        if pipisuyu == 0:
            anan = input("Tekrar oynamak isterseniz ""tekrar"" yaziniz.")
            if anan == "tekrar":
                run()
run()
```

Comment: Does this not answer his question?

Comment: no need for recursion though you could put the game conditions with the loop in a function and the condition to play in another loop in main

Comment: @APorter1031 kind of, but it's bad practice. With enough replays you'll blow the call stack and it'll crash. The other answer (putting it in a while loop) is both simpler and better.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't understand what `Tekrar oynamak isterseniz ""tekrar"" yaziniz` means, but it seems you need one more `while` loop, something like that:

```
anan = "tekrar"
while anan == "tekrar":
    pipisuyu = 1
    while pipisuyu == 1:
        ...
    anan = input("Tekrar oynamak isterseniz ""tekrar"" yaziniz.")
```

Comment: That means; "If you want to play again, type 'again'."
So that when I type the "again" input, the while loop needs to start again. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using just the features of Python that you have demonstrated you know, you could wrap the game in another while loop which does the resetting for you. Like so:

```
from random import randint

pipisuyu = 1
while True:
    while pipisuyu == 1:

        secim = input("Taas kagit....")
        AI = randint(0, 2)
        if secim == "Tas" and AI == 0:
            print ("Rakibiniz de Tas secti, berabere!")
        elif secim == "Tas" and AI == 1:
            print ("Rakibiniz kagit secmisti. Kaybettin!")
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Tas" and AI == 2:
            print ("Rakibiniz makas secmisti. Kazandiniz!")   
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Kagit" and AI == 0:  
            print ("Rakibiniz tas secmisti. Kazandiniz!")
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Kagit" and AI == 1: 
            print ("Rakibiniz de kagit secmisti. Berabere!")
        elif secim == "Kagit" and AI == 2:  
            print ("Rakibiniz makas secmisti. Kaybettiniz!")
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Makas" and AI == 0:
            print ("Rakibiniz tas secmisti. Kaybettiniz!")  
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Makas" and AI == 1:
            print ("Rakibiniz kagit secmisti. Kazandiniz!")  
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Makas" and AI == 2:
            print ("Rakibiniz de makas secmisti. Berabere!")
    pipisuyu = 1
```

However, to be slightly better, we would encase the game logic in a function and then make calls to that:

```
from random import randint

def playGame()
    while pipisuyu == 1:

        secim = input("Taas kagit....")
        AI = randint(0, 2)
        if secim == "Tas" and AI == 0:
            print ("Rakibiniz de Tas secti, berabere!")
        elif secim == "Tas" and AI == 1:
            print ("Rakibiniz kagit secmisti. Kaybettin!")
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Tas" and AI == 2:
            print ("Rakibiniz makas secmisti. Kazandiniz!")   
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Kagit" and AI == 0:  
            print ("Rakibiniz tas secmisti. Kazandiniz!")
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Kagit" and AI == 1: 
            print ("Rakibiniz de kagit secmisti. Berabere!")
        elif secim == "Kagit" and AI == 2:  
            print ("Rakibiniz makas secmisti. Kaybettiniz!")
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Makas" and AI == 0:
            print ("Rakibiniz tas secmisti. Kaybettiniz!")  
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Makas" and AI == 1:
            print ("Rakibiniz kagit secmisti. Kazandiniz!")  
            pipisuyu -= 1
        elif secim == "Makas" and AI == 2:
            print ("Rakibiniz de makas secmisti. Berabere!")

while True:
    playGame()
```